# JavaScript\REST check if current user belongs to SECURITY group

Tags: javascript, rest, security, authentication

By security group I mean groups like "Everyone", "Everyone except external users", "All Users (windows)" and so on. In people picker these groups come with EntityType "SecGroup".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes easier to do the reverse

Instead of checking rights you can check for failure with javascript:

```
try {

 //do something only admins can do, like accessing a List only they have access to

} catch(e) {

 //user without those rights will cause a JavaScript error end up here
 document.location="/youhavenorightstothesepages.aspx"
}
```